# NASM - error: label or instruction expected at start of line

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2015, nasm, bootloader, x86-16

I haven't written assembly code since Debug in MS-DOS 3.31 so *NASM* and the concept of using labels as variables in machine code is completely new to me. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Asmdude syntax highlighter. I'm using *NASM* version `2.12.01 compiled on Mar 17 2016`

I'm currently reading a PDF on operating system development called [Writing a Simple Operating System from Scratch](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf). I'm following one of the examples and I can't get the example to assemble.

Please forgive the antiquated code structure, I find it easier to read this way.

```
                    [BITS 16]
                    [ORG 0x7C00]
                    MOV BP, 0x8000 ; Set the base of the stack a little above where BIOS
                    MOV SP, BP ; loads our boot sector - so it won 't overwrite us.
ProgramOrigin:      MOV BX, StartText ; Put startup text into BX
                    CALL PrintString ;Call PrintString Function
                    JMP EndProgram ;Continue to end of program
PrintString:        PUSHA ; Push all registers onto stack 
                    MOV AH, 0x0E ; BIOS Teletype
NextChar:           MOV AL, [BX] ; Move the contents of memory segment at address in BX into AL
                    CMP AL, 0x00 ; if (AL == 00) it is the end of the string
                    JE EndPrint ; End function
                    INT 0x10 ;Interrupt to print character to screen
                    ADD BX, 1 ;ELSE increment address in BX
                    JMP nextChar ;Repeat
EndPrint:           POPA ;Return original Register values 
                    RET ;Return from function
StartText:          DB 'Kernel v0.01', 0x00
errText:            DB 'Error', 0x00
notFoundText:       DB 'Not Found', 0x00
EndProgram:         times 510 -($-$$) DB 0
                    DW 0xAA55
```

I did add some of my own code for the PrintString function, but I think I did that correctly because it worked in debug on my DOS VM

Comment: NASM is case sensitive when it comes to labels, try `JMP NextChar` instead of `JMP nextChar`. You should be able to assemble with something like `nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin` . Bootloader doesn't return anywhere so you should consider putting the code in an infinite cycle with something like `JMP $` or preferably `CLI` `EndLoop: HLT` `jmp EndLoop` when your code is finished.

Comment: Still getting the same error, thanx though.

Comment: The one in the post title "boot.asm:1: error: label or instruction expected at start of line". I re-formatted the arguments in the batch file just like you suggested:  G:\nasm\nasm.exe -f bin boot.asm -o bootsector.bin. I was just assembling to see the print function I added would really work.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015, ASMDude extension

Comment: Still the same thing.

Comment: NASM version 2.12.01 compiled on Mar 17 2016 - could you recommend a good IDE?

Comment: I copied it pasted it into a brand new file in notepad that I named boot2.asm, still no good, I also tried typing it into command line

Comment: Thank you, I'll spin up a simple text editor in c# and see if it works then.

Comment: You were correct, I wrote it to a file in ASCII format using a FileStream in a C# console application and it worked correctly. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: The editor you were using at first must be writing out the assembler file with the wrong text encoding. I have Visual Studio 2015 here without Asmdude and I successfully saved your boot code and was able to assemble it with NASM. Maybe Asmdude has done something, but I thought it was a syntax highlighter.

Comment: It is a syntax highlighter, Visual Studio must have the file types set to utf-8, I'm sure there's something in Tools>Options that'll fix the issue.

Comment: Yeah, that worked, that should have been obvious. Funny I jumped to the code solution first, lol. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working with [iuppiter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566081/iuppiter) it was determined that Visual Studio was writing the assembler file with wrong file encoding. The side effect was that *NASM* was unable to parse the file and exited with:

```
boot.asm:1: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
```

To resolve this problem in Visual Studio 2015 one can save the file with a different encoding using this process:

1. Open the assembler file
2. Select `File/Save as...` on the menu
3. At the bottom of the file selector window click the down arrow beside the `Save` button at the bottom
4. Click `Save with encoding...`
5. Select `Western European (Windows) Codepage 1252` (This should be plain text)
6. Click `OK`